# converting from void* to int in c++

Tags: c++, int, mqtt, void-pointers

I am working in a mqtt application and when i receive the information of the payload from the mqtt broker and try to convert it from the void* that is message->payload to an int as

```
signed int var_1=*((int*) message->payload);
```

instead of converting it to the number it is converting it to another one, to see this I am using the following code:

```
printf("Message:%s\n",message->payload);
printf("Message:%i\n",var_1);
```

Which shows:

```
Message:-58
Message:3683629
```

I also thought about the payload being a string, but if I use the stoi function it gives me the error:

```
can not convert from ´void*´ to ´int´ with stoi function.
```

Comment: what are you asking here exactly? what's `message->payload` supposed to be anyway? a buffer representing `int` or ascii string?

Comment: The real question is, how is the message sent? The sender did something to create a payload from his data. You need to reverse this process.

Comment: `instead of converting it to the number it is converting it to another one` What is the number that you expected then?

Answer (score 1):

In C++ you can't automatically convert from `const void*` to `const char*`.

You need an explicit static cast:

```
int i=atoi(static_cast<const char*>(message->payload));
```

Notice I've used `atoi()` which is a C library function (`#include <cstdlib>`).

There's little point converting it to a `std::string` just to parse that to an `int`.

All this assumes you're correct to think the payload is a character encoded decimal integer in a c-style string.

Answer (score 1):

> [I] try to convert it from the `void*` ... to an `int`.

OK. The first step is to figure out the type of object that is being transported. As the documentation of MQTT says:

> MQTT is data-agnostic and it totally depends on the use case how the payload is structured. It’s completely up to the sender if it wants to send ...

---

> as
>
> ```
> signed int var_1=*((int*) message->payload);
> ```

Now, this is correct, if the pointer points to an object of type `int`. It is a reasonable guess, but you should not be guessing - except as last resort - for the type of the object. You should study the sender whether by reading documentation or code to find out the type of the pointed object.

> instead of converting it to the number it is converting it to another one

So, either you've been expecting the wrong value, or you guessed the type wrong. The solution is to stop guessing and find out the correct type.

---

> I also thought about the payload being a string, but if I use the stoi function it gives me the error:
>
> ```
> can not convert from ´void*´ to ´int´ with stoi function.
> ```

The error seems to be exceptionally clear. The argument of `stoi` is `const std::string& str`, not `void*`. `void*` is not implicitly convertible to `std::string`. Exactly how to do such conversion depends on what type of object `void*` points to (or sometimes, what type of data it *contains*).

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite understand if message->payload holds the number itself or a string representation for it.
If message->payload holds the **memory location** in which the number is stored, so var_1 holds the **value**.
Therefore, you cannot expect those values to be the same.
Regarding stoi - it receives a string that hold number, but as a string. For example -

```
std::string num = "1234";
int convertedNumber = stoi(num);
```